# Mockk: Mock a global function with overloads

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

Mockk added support for [mocking global functions](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/518).

However, when they have overloads there's a problem.

For example if you try to mock `delay()` with `mockkStatic(::delay)` you encounter this error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines
public suspend fun delay(duration: Duration): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines
```

Is there a way to mock a global function that has overloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That one is a bit tricky, because it seems to be impossible to access the declaring class of such a global function using Kotlin reflection. However, it is possible to use Java reflection, if you know at least one other function in the same file that is not overloaded.

Let's for instance assume that you mean `delay` of coroutines, there is the function `awaitCancellation` defined in the same file.

We can use that to access the Java class that declares `delay` and query it for the right implementation of `delay`:

```
val declaringClass = ::awaitCancellation.javaMethod!!.declaringClass
val methods = declaringClass.declaredMethods
val ref = methods.mapNotNull { it.kotlinFunction }
    .filter { it.name == "delay" }
    .first { it.parameters[0].type == Long::class.createType() }
mockkStatic(ref)
```

In this example, `ref` points to the implementation of `delay` that takes a `Long` as parameter.

For the other implementation we would need to replace `Long` with `Duration` in the last condition.

Comment: It's a pity there's not an easier way. But nicely done, thanks!